# Images disappear from page when other image is displayed

Tags: javascript

I have some tabs and there are several buttons in the third tab which display different images when clicked. The problem is that when any of these buttons are clicked and an image is displayed, all the other images on my web page disappear. Perhaps this is because I'm not appending the images to that particular tab?
What do I need to add/change in my code to fix this issue?

```js
// tabs
function selectTab(tabIndex) {

    document.getElementById('tab1Content').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tab2Content').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tab3Content').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tab4Content').style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById('tab1').classList.remove("active");
    document.getElementById('tab2').classList.remove("active");
    document.getElementById('tab3').classList.remove("active");
    document.getElementById('tab4').classList.remove("active");


    document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex + 'Content').style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex).classList.add("active");
}

// Colour Swatch
function showImage(el, id = 'tab3Content') {
    var images = document.getElementById('img1');
    Array.from(images).forEach(i => i.style.display = 'none');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.style.marginTop = '-50px'
    img.setAttribute("width", "850");
    img.setAttribute("height", "500");
    img.setAttribute("src", "");;
    if(el.getAttribute('data-id') == '1'){
      }
    else if(el.getAttribute('data-id') == '2'){
    img.setAttribute("src", "");;
    }
    else if(el.getAttribute('data-id') == '3'){
        img.setAttribute("src", "");;
      }
      else if(el.getAttribute('data-id') == '4'){
        img.setAttribute("src", "");;
      }
  
  document.getElementById(id).appendChild(img);
}
```

```css
.tab {
    border-radius: 0.5px;
}
  .tabButton {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color:  rgb(45, 68, 117);
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    color:  rgb(45, 68, 117);
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    margin-right: -75px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
           <button class="tabButton active" id="tab1" onClick="selectTab(1);">Tab1</button>
           <button class="tabButton" id="tab2" onClick="selectTab(2);">Tab2</button>
           <button class="tabButton" id="tab3" onClick="selectTab(3);">Tab3</button>
           <button class="tabButton" id="tab4" onClick="selectTab(4);">Tab4</button>
           <br />
           
           <div class="contentTab" id="tab1Content" style="display: block;">
            <div class="tabcontent">
             <p>tab 1</p>
                <img class="img-position" src="">
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="contentTab" id="tab2Content" style="display: none;">
            <p>Tab 2</p>
            <img src="">
           </div>
           <div class="contentTab colour-swatch" id="tab3Content" style="display: none;">
<img id="img1">
           <button class="colour-btn colour-btn--1"data-id="1"  onClick="showImage(this)"></button>
           <button class="colour-btn colour-btn--2" data-id="2" onClick="showImage(this)"></button>
           <button class="colour-btn colour-btn--3"data-id="3"  onClick="showImage(this)"></button>
           <button class="colour-btn colour-btn--4"data-id="4"  onClick="showImage(this)"></button>
           </div>
           <div class="contentTab" id="tab4Content" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container">
            <p>tab4</p>
            <img class="img" src=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS... you're missing two closing `</div>` tags at the end

Comment: Also, why you use sometimes `<img src="">` than in another tab you have `<img class="img" src="">` and than suddenly also `<img class="img-position" src="">`

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');` to a more specific selector.
`'img'` targets every image tag (`<img>`) on your page.

Perhaps `var images = document.querySelectorAll('.img');` is what you want (or `'.img-position`?) with a *dot* to point to a *class*.

Comment: Thanks, I have now changed it to this ```var images = document.getElementById('img1');``` which fixed that but has caused another problem. Now, when different buttons are clicked, displaying different images, the previous images stay on the screen rather than being hidden and only showing one image at a time.  @RokoC.Buljan